# ASP.NET Core 2.2 - accessing the StaticFileOption RequestPath later in code

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-staticfile

In Startup.cs Configure function I do something like this:

```
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"\\server\somepath\someimages"),
            RequestPath = "/images"
        });
```

Later, say in the controller, I'd like to not hard-code:

```
        string ImageImLookingFor = "/images" + foo.jpg;
```

Instead I'd like to do something like:

```
        string ImageImLookingFor = SomeObjectThatGivesMe.RequestPath + foo.jpg;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure if it is possible but a workaround can be an appsettings key and read it from both locations.

ex:
in your appsettings

```
{
 "ImagesPath" : '/images"
}
```

in Starup.cs

```
   app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"\\server\somepath\someimages"),
        RequestPath = Configuration["ImagesPath"]
    });
```

In your contorller

```
    string ImageImLookingFor = configuration.RequestPath + foo.jpg;
```

You can make the configuration file a strong type and replace it with `IOptions<ImageConfiguration>` where `ImageConfiguration` is a class that has `ImagesPath` property

Answer (score 1):

You could try to configure `StaticFileOptions` with `services.Configure` like

```
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<StaticFileOptions>(options => {
            options.FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"xxx");
            options.RequestPath = "/images";
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {            
        app.UseStaticFiles(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<StaticFileOptions>>().Value);            
    }
}
```

And then access it by `IOptions<StaticFileOptions>` like

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly StaticFileOptions _options;
    public HomeController(IOptions<StaticFileOptions> options)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _options = options.Value;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Ok(_options.RequestPath);
    }        
}
```

Comment: I had played around with FileProviders, but one of the things I find odd is that I can't figure out how to retrieve the "FileProvider".  Well, I can get the provider, that's incorrect, it doesn't give me the path/string at all (except when debugging).  I can get the requestPath through options.Value.RequestPath, but I can't get the actual @"xxx" string when accessing options.Value.FileProvider.